# real solution for the equation $\dot{f}=1-f^2$ with initial condition $f(0)=f_0>1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am puzzled by the following question.

Let $f=f(t)$, I am trying to solve

$$\dot{f}=1-f^2$$
with initial condition, $$f(0)=f_0>1$$
The general solution is 
$$f(t) = \tanh(t + \tanh^{-1}(f_0))$$
however, the solution becomes a complex number when $f_0>1$. Which is not what I need. I derived this equation to describe a physics process with damping rate decreases over time, so I need a real solution, which is quite easy to get through the numerical method, but when I try to get a real analytical solution it seems quite hard. What is the reason for that?

Comment: Let $t_0=\tanh^{-1} f_0$. Then the argument-addition identity for tanh yields $$\tanh(t+t_0) = \frac{\tanh(t)+\tanh(t_0)}{1+\tanh(t)\tanh(t_0)} = \frac{\tanh(t)+f_0}{1+f_0 \tanh t},$$ which appears to be a valid solution for all $t>0$ for any $f_0\geq 0$.

Comment: @Semiclassical see my answer. solutions with absolute value less than one really are $\tanh (t - t_0).$ If $f > 1,$ it is $\frac{1}{\tanh (t-t_0)}$ with $t > t_0.$ Separate for $f < -1$ although similar appearance as formulas, same with $t < t_0$

Comment: @WillJagy As far as I can tell, the solution I wrote down covers the case of $\coth(t+t_0)$ with the identification $f_0=\coth t_0$ in that instance. That said, my formula has one big conceptual disadvantage: it's not obvious that the solutions form a family of horizontal translates.

Comment: @Semiclassical Sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are constant solutions of an ODE in one variable, there is a change of behavior across it. Your ODE has constant solutions $f=1$ and $f=-1.$  **It is the strip in between where the $f = \tanh t$ solution happens**. Outside the strip, as in you $f_0 > 1,$ we actually get $\frac{1}{\tanh t}.$ Sometimes this is called $\coth t.$

Diagram; all other solutions are horizontal translations of these curves

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe so
$$\int\frac{df}{(1-f)(1+f)}=\frac{1}{2}(\int\frac{d(f+1)}{f+1}-\int\frac{d(1-f)}{1-f}) $$
$\Rightarrow $ 
$$ \frac{1}{2}log(\frac{1+f}{1-f})=t+C$$ $$ \frac{1+f}{1-f}=e^{2t}C$$
$$f(t)=\frac{e^{2t}C-1}{e^{2t}C+1} $$
from the initial conditions we obtain
$$C=\frac{1+f_0}{1-f_0} $$
$$f(t)=\frac{e^{2t}(1+f_0)-(1-f_0)}{e^{2t}(1+f_0)+(1-f_0)} $$